# WordPress custom post type archive widget to display only CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I currently have a CPT changelog, and on my custom sidebar I want to display the archives of only this CPT and not all the other posts.

For example :

January 2017 -> should display only CPT changelog post 
And so on.

Here's what I have tried so far :

```
function custom_changelog_getarchives_where($where)
{
   $where = str_replace("post_type = 'post'", "post_type IN ( 'post', 
  'changelog' )", $where);

  return $where;
}

add_filter('getarchives_where', 'custom_changelog_getarchives_where');
```

The above snippet now returns archives of my CPT but it also include the normal posts as well

How do I display only the CPT?

Comment: `$where = str_replace("post_type = 'post'", "post_type = 'changelog' ", $where);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your CPT to the list and using an `IN` clause, if you just want to display your CPT, replace the `WHERE` clause with only your CPT, like this:

```
$where = str_replace("post_type = 'post'", "post_type = 'changelog'", $where);
```

Comment: hey nath, can you answer this -https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/359003/how-to-create-a-separate-archive-widget-only-for-my-cpt-portfolio